# Carbon, finding if a time is within 9am to 5pm

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to check if a time is within 9am and 5pm, but not sure how to do it.

I grab my current time: `$AUTime = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));`

And I know I can check if it's a weekday very easily but not sure how to check if it is between 9am-5pm.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain `->between($first, $second)` to the `Carbon` instance you want to compare to. Do note that `$first` and `$second` must be `Carbon` instances as well.

Here's the url to the [docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison).

Comment: From my understanding $first or $second need to be `datetime` Carbon instances like you said. That means I need to pass it a date? I need it to be the same date, just 9am that day. If that makes any sense?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Tho I do think you could go `Carbon` all the way and generate the `DateTime` format using the `Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $tz)` function ([docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation))

Comment: The issue is I don't know what the `$year, $month` etc will be for the time I'm checking.

Comment: Can't you access it from the `Carbon` instance you are checking? Like this `$AUTime->year` using `getters` [docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters)

Answer (score 0):

something like below

```
$AUTime = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
$startTime = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
$endTime = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));

//now set start and end time to limit
$startTime->hour = 09;
$startTime->minute = 00;

$endTime->hour = 17;
$endTime->minute = 00;

$AUTime->between($start, $end); // will return true if its between 9AM to 5PM
```